# GXT theme-replace stopped working

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

For some reason, my custom appearance is not being used to replace gxt class any longer (worked yesterday).

All I did was comment out this part, recompile application and then revert it and recompile again:

```
<replace-with class='com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.header.TestColumnHeaderAppearance'>
    <when-type-is class='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnHeader.ColumnHeaderAppearance' />
</replace-with>
```

Relevant code:

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.Base" />

    <replace-with class='com.acdlabs.Test_portal.web.theme.client.header.TestColumnHeaderAppearance'>
        <when-type-is class='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnHeader.ColumnHeaderAppearance' />
    </replace-with> 
</module>

public class TestColumnHeaderAppearance extends ColumnHeaderDefaultAppearance {

    public interface TestColumnHeaderResources extends ColumnHeaderResources {
        @Override
        @Source({ "com/sencha/gxt/theme/base/client/grid/ColumnHeader.gss", "TestColumnHeader.gss" })
        public TestColumnHeaderStyle style();
    }

    public interface TestColumnHeaderStyle extends DefaultColumnHeaderStyles {
        String filterIcon();
    }

    public TestColumnHeaderAppearance() {
        super(GWT.<ColumnHeaderResources> create(TestColumnHeaderResources.class));
    }

}

public class TestColumnHeader<M> extends ColumnHeader<M> {

    public TestColumnHeader(Grid<M> container, ColumnModel<M> cm, ColumnHeaderAppearance appearance) {
        super(container, cm, appearance);
        if (appearance.styles() instanceof TestColumnHeaderStyle) {  
            styles = (TestColumnHeaderStyle) appearance.styles(); // <-- this is never reached and I that's why I get exceptions like "Cannot read property 'filterIcon_0_g$' of undefined"
        }
    }
}
```

Can my browser be caching themes and ignoring my TestColumnHeaderAppearance? 
Added a comment in TestColumnHeader, which shows that TestColumnHeaderAppearance is not being loaded.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It's working in different browser (fire fox), so it does seem like cache problem. Though I clear cache of the browser that's not working (chrome) and still no change. Deleted /target folter, recompile everything, still no changes.

**EDIT 2**

When application is built in .war format and deployed to tomcat, everything works (I can see that styling has changed). Might be a problem with super dev mode then or its configuration.

**WeblibTheme.gwt.xml**

```
<module>

    <inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.Base" />

    <!-- Buttons -->

    <replace-with class="com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.button.TestWebButtonCellAppearance">
        <when-type-is class="com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.ButtonCell.ButtonCellAppearance" />
    </replace-with> 

    <replace-with class="com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.field.TestWebDualListFieldAppearance">
        <when-type-is class="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.DualListField.DualListFieldAppearance" />
    </replace-with>    

    <replace-with class='com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.header.TestColumnHeaderAppearance'>
        <when-type-is class='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnHeader.ColumnHeaderAppearance' />
    </replace-with>

    <!-- Slider -->
    <replace-with class="com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.slider.TestWebSliderAppearance">
    <any>
      <when-type-is class="com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.SliderCell.SliderAppearance" />
      <when-type-is class="com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.SliderCell.HorizontalSliderAppearance" />
    </any>
    </replace-with> 

    <!-- TreeAppearance -->
    <replace-with class="com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.tree.TestTreeAppearance">
        <when-type-is class="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.tree.Tree.TreeAppearance"/>
    </replace-with>

    <!-- DatePicker -->
    <replace-with class="com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.client.datepicker.TestDatePickerAppearance">
        <when-type-is class="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.DatePicker.DatePickerAppearance"/>
    </replace-with>
</module>
```

**TestWeb.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='TestWeb'>

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.inject.Inject' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.resources.Resources' />

    <!-- Other module inherits -->
    <inherits name='com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp' />
    <inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.Dispatch' />
    <inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt20.AtmosphereGwt20" />
    <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart' />
    <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder" />
    <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.Crypto" />
    <inherits name="com.test.chemwidgets.ChemWidgets" />
    <inherits name="com.test.gxt_widgets.GxtWidgets" />
    <inherits name="com.test.Test_portal.web.theme.WeblibTheme" />

    <collapse-property name="user.agent.os" values="*" />
    <collapse-property name="gxt.user.agent" values="air, safari*, chrome" />
    <collapse-property name="gxt.user.agent" values="ie9, ie10" />
    <collapse-property name="gxt.user.agent" values="gecko*" />

    <replace-with class='com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.engine.VML'>
        <when-type-is class='com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.Surface' />
        <any>
            <when-property-is name='user.agent' value='ie8' />
        </any>
    </replace-with>

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='com.test.Test_portal.web.client.TestWeb' />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />

    <set-configuration-property name='gin.ginjector'
        value='com.test.Test_portal.web.client.gin.ClientGinjector' />


    <set-configuration-property name='gin.ginjector'
        value='com.test.Test_portal.web.client.gin.ClientGinjector' />

    <!-- By default (GWT 2.7.0) CssResources uses CSS instead of GSS -->
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.enableGss"
        value="true" />


    <!-- GWT Compiler converts all .css files to .gss, if value for CssResource.enableGss 
        is true -->
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.conversionMode"
        value="strict" />


    <!-- The default for GSS in UiBinder -->
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder"
        value="true" />

    <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
     <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames"
      value="true" />
     <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers"
      value="true" />

    <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames"
        value="true" />
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers"
        value="true" />
</module>
```

**TestWeb-dev.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='TestWeb'>

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name="com.test.Test_portal.web.TestWeb" />

    <!-- Collapsing all permutations into one. -->
    <collapse-all-properties />

</module>
```

**EDIT (fixed, no idea why):**

Cleared my AppData\Local\Temp\ folder and recompiled the application. Maybe super dev mode ignored the changes made to modules until as long as temp folder held previous version?

Comment: can you provide the complete module descriptor?

Comment: @ElHoss edited question